# The unique representation of Heisenberg Group.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

How can we construct the unique-up-to-isomorphism irreducible representation of [Heisenberg Group.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group)

Comment: Why unique ? Take a faithful representation and then one which is not.

Comment: I edited it, again

Comment: Why do you think this group has a unique irreducible representation?

Comment: I mean , unique-up-to-isomorphism.

Comment: Why do you think this group has a unique-up-to-isomorphism irreducible representation?

Comment: We need to construct such unique representation for working on metaplectic representation.

Comment: In what way does that answer my question?

Comment: I have seen in several lectures this fact, but without details

Comment: Of **what** fact? Unless you make the question precise, the fact you are referring to is a non-fact (It should be obvious that every group has at least the trivial representation, which is always irreducible...). What Heisenberg group exactly do you have in mind? What sort of representations are you considering?

Comment: You have been participating in this site for a long while now, and have asked quite a few questions! It would no hurt to try to strive to put more work into your questions, really: you would get much better results.

Comment: Mariano Suárez-Alvarez@ You can see for instance http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jthomas7/GeomQuant/Lecture3.pdf part 1.1. But it is not clear

Comment: I could see that, but it is *you* who are interested in getting an answer, and then it is you who should explain exactly what you want. If you do not know exactly what you want (as seems to be the case) you should explain that, or something. In any case, I am sorry to say that I will now stop paying attention to this question: this should not be that hard.

Comment: could you tell me, which requirement I should add for more clearness for instance?

Comment: I have already said this, but here we go: (1) you do not tell us in the question **what** Heisenberg group you are talking about (there are quite a few things that go under that name; you added a link to Wikipedia, but there the variant you seem to want is not even mentioned there!) (2) It is not true that the group (whatever it is) has a unique irreducible representation, so you are really asking about why it has a unique irred. rep. *satisfying certain conditions* which you have not bothered to explain.

Comment: Your question is about a group which you did nott specify sufficiently well and about a class of representations which you did not specify at all. It is impossible to know what you had in mind when you wrote it!

Answer (score 3):

The link you've provided in the comments on Dietrich Burde's answer illuminates the question quite significantly.  The definition of Heisenberg Group there is $H(V)=V\oplus U(1)$ for some symplectic vector space $(V,\omega)$.  Here $\omega$ is a nondegenerate, skew-symmetric, bilinear form.  The group law is:

$$(v,z)\cdot (w,u)=(v+w,\exp(\frac{i}{2}\omega(v,w))zu)$$

Next, choose a Lagrangian subspace $L\subset V$, which is a maximal isotropic subspace with respect to the form $\omega$.  With such a choice, we can define the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_L$ as done so in the link (the completion of a space of smooth, $L^2$ functions satisfying some translation identity).  It is on this Hilbert space that we define the action of $H(V)$ to be:

$$(v,z)\cdot \phi(x)=z\phi(x-v)\exp(\frac{i}{2}\omega(v,x))$$

Notice that group elements $(0,z)$ act via scalar multiplication.  This representation can also be viewed as being induced from the irreducible $1$-dimensional representation of the subgroup $L\oplus U(1)$ via projection onto $U(1)$.  I'm not exactly sure how the equivalence works.

Now, as claimed in the link, it seems that any representation of $H(V)$ in which $U(1)$ just acts as scalar multiplication is equivalent to the one constructed here, and so up to isomorphism, our representation is independent of our choice of Lagrangian, $L\subset V$.

Not sure if this is any more helpful.  As others have noted, it would be faster in the future if you would give more context for your questions.  As it was stated, it was very difficult to see exactly what you were asking.

Comment: thank a lot for your new edition, but my problem is as same as your statement which you said" I'm not exactly sure how the equivalence works." on this lecture

Comment: Also you wrote "This representation can also be viewed as being induced from the irreducible 1-dimensional representation of the subgroup $L⊕U(1)$ via projection onto $U(1)$". My question is why?

Comment: @Jared: Incidentally, it is not the direct sum of anything either. It is definitely indecomposable, since decomposability would imply that there exists a basis where all upper triangular matrices  are block-diagonal with blocks of size 1 and 2 on the diagonal. One can easily check that already the individual matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ does not admit such a basis. It is a very good illustration of how different irreducibility is from indecomposability.

Comment: @h.jolany: If we accept as fact that up to isomorphism there is only one representation in which $U(1)$ acts as scalar multiplication, then we see that the induced representation described must be equivalent to the representation given by the explicit formula, because the projection $(v,z)\mapsto z$ will act by scalar multiplication.  Beyond that, I can't see why the two descriptions are equivalent.

Comment: @Jared: it is true for finite groups and for compact groups, but not in general. If you recall your favourite proof of complete reducibility, it uses averaging over the group in one way or the other.

Answer (score 3):

There is a result of David Mumford (see also the related result of Marshall Stone and John von Neumann) stating that there
exists a unique irreducible representation of the algebraic Heisenberg group such that its center acts normally.
Here algebraic Heisenberg groups are affine group schemes $G$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ lying in a central extension
$$
1\rightarrow G_m \rightarrow G \rightarrow K \rightarrow 0,
$$
where $K$ is a finite abelian affine group scheme and $G_m = Spec ( k[t, t^{−1}])$ is the center of $G$. A proof with references can found in the thesis of Matt Collins.

On the other hand, the real Heisenberg group has many linear representations, and in particular a faithful linear one with upper-trinagular matrices of size $3$ (see below resp. above).

Comment: The original theorem of Stone and von Neumann refers to unitary, strongly continuous reps, iirc. This algebraic variant came later, I imagine?

Comment: Mariano Suárez-Alvarez@ But, I think we need to work on Lagrangian subspaces, I was waiting for an answer by Lagrangian subspace construction

Comment: @Mariano: yes, you a right. The algebraic variant is due to Mumford. I will correct this, thank you.

Comment: You can see for instance http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jthomas7/GeomQuant/Lecture3.pdf part 1.1. But it is not clear

Comment: In second comment,I wrote for you that, I edited my question. Also your answer is completely different with such type of construction.

Comment: You have to consider by what requirements you obtain uniqueness. This is not true in general. Indeed, you have to be more precise in the formulation of your question.

Comment: Dietrich Burde@ So you mean the statement of part 1.1 of this lecture is noct correct in general? maths.ed.ac.uk/~jthomas7/GeomQuant/Lecture3.pdf . can you give a counterexample? also which requirements I could put in my question which I forgot it?